# How to prevent VSCode from automatically wrapping WebdriverIO and Mocha.js code in parentheses?

Tags: javascript, testing, automation, mocha.js, webdriver-io

I am trying to write some tests using WebdriverIO and Mocha.js on VSCode, but when I write the code, VSCode automatically wraps the code with parentheses and it makes my code fail.

How can I close this feature?

When I write the code like this, it cannot find the element (because of the async mode I think.)
[I don't want these parentheses but VSCode automatically adds them](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DNS10.png)

When I write the code like this, all the buttons are clicked without any problem.
[When I write the code like this, all the buttons are clicked without any problem.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N6SPi.png)